Using Extent Report in Jmeter overrides the results and displays the last executed sampler
I am doing API Functional automation testing in Jmeter. I tried using ExtentReport 5.0.6 for Report generation. This Report overrides the results and displays only the last executed sampler.
Added Beanshell Assertion at the root of each ThreadGroup with the below Groovy code:
//request data
String requestData = new String(prev.SamplerData);
//String requestData = new String(requestData);
props.put("propRequestData", requestData);
//response data
String respData = new String(prev.ResponseData);
//String respData = new String(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
props.put("propResponse", respData);
//response code
String respCode = new String(prev.ResponseCode);
props.put("propRespCode",respCode);
//response message
String respMessage = new String(prev.ResponseMessage);
props.put("propRespMessage",respMessage);


And, added JSR223 Listener at the root of the test plan with the following groovy code:
import com.aventstack.extentreports.*;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.*;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.*;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ViewName;

ExtentSparkReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest extentTest;
if(extent == null) {
// create the HtmlReporter
htmlReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter("C:/API-Results.html");

//configure report
htmlReporter.config().setOfflineMode(true);
//htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Results");
htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
htmlReporter.config().setReportName("CKPAT API Results");                                                                                                                                                   htmlReporter.viewConfigurer().viewOrder().as(new ViewName[] {ViewName.DASHBOARD, ViewName.TEST}).apply();

// create ExtentReports
extent = new ExtentReports();

// attach reporter to ExtentReports
extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
extent.setReportUsesManualConfiguration(true); 

// Show Env section and set data on dashboard
extent.setSystemInfo("Tool","JMeter");
extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
} 

//extent.setSystemInfo("Test Time","${currentTime}");
//stringify test info
String threadName = sampler.getThreadName();
String samplerName = sampler.getName();
String requestData = props.get("propRequestData");
String respCode = props.get("propRespCode");
String respMessage = props.get("propRespMessage");
String responseData = props.get("propResponse");

// create test
extentTest = extent.createTest(threadName+" - "+samplerName);
//test.assignCategory("API Testing");

// analyze sampler result
if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok") == "false") {
   log.error("FAILED: "+samplerName);
   print("FAILED: "+samplerName);
   extentTest.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel("FAILED:  "+sampler.getName(),ExtentColor.RED));

} else if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok") == "true") {
    if(responseData.contains("@error")) {
        log.info("FAILED: "+sampler.getName());
         print("FAILED: "+sampler.getName());
        extentTest.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel("FAILED:   "+sampler.getName(),ExtentColor.RED));

    } else if (responseData.contains("{")) {
            log.info("Passed: "+sampler.getName());
        print("Passed: "+sampler.getName());
            extentTest.pass(MarkupHelper.createLabel("Passed:   "+sampler.getName(),ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }
} else {
    log.error("Something is really wonky");
    print("Something is really wonky");
    extentTest.fatal("Something is really wonky");
}

//info messages
    extentTest.info("RequestData:   "+requestData);
    extentTest.info("Response Code and Message:    "+respCode+"   "+respMessage);
    extentTest.info("ResponseData:    "+responseData);

extent.flush();


but, when i execute the samplers, i get the extent report with only the last executed sampler.
What am i doing wrong here? Experts, please advice on this.

According to JMeter documentation:

Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

So you need to distinguish the metrics coming from different Thread Groups for example by adding thread group name or its index as the property postfix because you're basically overwriting the property with the value of the next Sampler
Also be aware that if you put an Assertion or a Listener as top level test element it will be executed after each Sampler in its scope so if you have more than one Sampler in the Thread Group - consider adding its label to the property name as well.
Also for functional testing Beanshell can be ok but I would recommend switching to Groovy anyway because it's way more powerful language which supports new Java language features while Beanshell is stuck at Java 5 language level and also adds some syntax sugar on top. More information: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
